# Modeling large datasets to avoid long-running queries

Tags: neo4j

I am currently playing with a neo4j database that consists of 3 types of node: “User”, “Merchant” and “Offer”.

Users click on offers, and make purchases from merchants. So, the following relationships exist:

```
(:User)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(:Merchant)
(:User)-[:CLICKED_ON]->(:Offer)
```

I want to perform a cypher query that will recommend merchants to a particular user, based on how many other users with similar tastes have purchased from that merchant. So a pretty standard collaborative filtering query, I believe.

The query looks like this:

```
MATCH(u:User{userId:1234)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(:Merchant)<-[:PURCHASED_FROM]-(:User)-[r:PURCHASED_FROM]->(newMerchants:Merchant)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(newMerchants)
RETURN DISTINCT newMerchants.name, newMerchants.merchantId, count(r) AS rel_count
ORDER BY rel_count DESC
LIMIT 30
```

My problem is that this query will take a LONG time to run. IN fact, it’ll take so long I haven’t seen it finish yet. Removing the count() aggregate functions will help things, but I need to order by this count of relationships so that the user sees the merchants most relevant to them.

I believe the problem is caused by the sheer number of nodes and relationships in graph, and the number of traversals that then occur when the above query is executed.

It’s not uncommon for a single merchant node to have >1m :PURCHASED_FROM relationships.

I figure that this must be a problem that comes up fairly frequently in large graphs. What modelling approaches are available to lessen the number of traversals required at query time?

Comment: Not related to your data model, but have you tried any performance tuning configuration changes? There's an overview of different options here: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple `PURCHASED_FROM` relationships between a `User` and a `Merchant`?  If so, it might make more sense to use `MERGE` to create just one between each pair and store a `count` property on the relationship.  Then maybe you could sum that `count` like so:

```
MATCH(u:User{userId:1234)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(:Merchant)<-[:PURCHASED_FROM]-(:User)-[r:PURCHASED_FROM]->(newMerchants:Merchant)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:PURCHASED_FROM]->(newMerchants)
RETURN DISTINCT newMerchants.name, newMerchants.merchantId, sum(r.count) AS rel_count
ORDER BY rel_count DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: There certainly are scenarios where there are more than a single PURCHASED_FROM relationship between two nodes. It makes perfect sense to flatten those relationships to a single relationship with a count property - thanks for the suggestion.